# Php disable function call parameter check

Tags: php, function, parameters, arguments

Is there a way to disable parameter count check in function call?
Example :

```
function test_function($var1, $var2, $var3) // function declaration  
test_function(1,2) // function call
```

I am looking for a way for the function call with lesser parameter to work.
Or initializing the function declaration with default value will work?
Example: `function test_function($var1, $var2, $var3 = 0)`

Comment: _"Or initializing the function declaration with default value will work?"_ - sure, why shouldn't it? That is what is explicitly explained in the manual, after all - https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default

Comment: [should get you going](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)

Comment: "_Or initializing the function declaration with default value will work?_" What's stopping you from trying that out yourself?

Answer (score 0):

```
function test_function($var1 = null, $var2 = null, $var3 = null)
```

and you can call

```
function test_function();
function test_function($var1);
function test_function($var1 , $var2)
```

arguments must have different names